# "The system cannot find the path specified."/ "The notebook list is empty"

Tags: python, directory, jupyter-notebook, windows-10, command-prompt

Please I need help with an issue.

I can't access the folders in my Documents folder on Command Prompt. I also noticed this problem with my Jupyter Notebook. The system does not detect the folders in my Documents folder. It returns an error message on Command Prompt which says, "The system cannot find the path specified.". On Jupyter Notebook, it's still the same issue; it says, "The notebook list is empty." But my Documents folder is not empty.

Please, what is causing this issue?

I use a Windows 10 HP computer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I realized **OneDrive** creates a **backup** from folders such as Documents, Desktop, Pictures,...

You can **open the OneDrive folder** on your computer or in Jupyter notebook and see all files are there.

In order to **access** them **via Jupyter notebook** directly, you can type **cd OneDrive** in **Command Prompt** then **start Jupyter Notebook** there. Then all the files will be shown.

For example in **Windows 10**, I use these lines in Command Prompt:

**cd OneDrive**

**python -m notebook**

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the particular folder. On the respective folder, right-click --> give access to-->. In the appearing list, make sure that "**view and edit**" access is granted to all users if you have more than 1.

(To do this you will require admin privileges. So make sure in your windows PC you have logged on as an admin.)

Comment: It's my personal computer. I gave access and full control to everyone. It still isn't working.

Comment: I think I've figured out the issue. My Documents folder were being saved in OneDrive. I've moved them from OneDrive now. Thanks for your time!